# Place macros in a library or convert them to functions?

Tags: c, embedded

I've been making some macros in class because thats what my prof taught me but for the actual projects we are told to make a library to make our lifes easier. Can i put macros in there? Or should i convert them to functions? if so could someone help me with converting one of these because i'm a little confused about the return types and so on.

```
#define BV(bit) (1 << (bit))
#define setBit(byte, mask) (byte |= (mask))
#define clearBit(byte, mask) (byte &= ~(mask))
```

Comment: It seems to me that `setBit(byte, mask)` would return a `byte`. Prototype could be: `byte setBit(byte value, byte mask);` Since this appears to be homework, I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Macros belong to header files. So, you can have a special header file which contains them. Functions, on the other hand can go into a pre-compiled library.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove these macros and not use them at all.

Code such as `byte |= 1u << 3` is the most readable form. All C programmers immediately understand what the code does. If you have trouble reading/understanding bitwise operators, then macros is not the solution to that problem.

Code such as `setBit(byte, BV(3))` is completely unreadable. To understand this, the C programmer must first learn your secret macro language. They shouldn't be forced to learn that language when they already know C.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to inline functions and put them in a header file, or you could leave them as macros and put them in a header file.

Either way you will only have a header file, and you can include that from multiple different source files.

I wouldn't recommend putting things as simple as this into a library that gets compiled separately.